# How to keep away Wasp, hornet, tanboori away

Tags: safety, insects

I have gone through different sites but no one knows how to keep safe from tanboori (in Urdu language) , Wasp and other similar insects like Hornet. For reference see this picture:

https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDuPFow6ijkl8Hl-FYHZV8JQQXCIhWDw36LiTEx9jSV3d6Cn0f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insect repellents do not deter wasps or hornets, and insecticides can be dangerous, especially around areas where you live or eat. Try a [wasp trap](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Wasp-Trap) (and [here](http://www.prairiestory.com/2010/09/homemade-wasp-trap.html)), baited with their favorite foods (e.g. sweet-smelling fruit or sugar water). The trap will not eliminate all wasps, but reduces the chance of getting stung.

Be sure not to hang it *too* close to your living space, since the bait attracts them, and be careful disposing of them.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of fake wasp nest deterrents like this one:

[image]

Wasps are territorial and avoid areas with an unfamiliar nest.  These deterrents seem to work well for wasps and yellow jackets and are even somewhat decorative.

Comment: I have never heard of this.  This article does not answer it, but the comments, though anecdotal, seem to get good results.  https://www.scienceworld.ca/blog/do-fake-wasp-nests-fool-wasps

Comment: This may be a very good idea. But people may not have good awareness about it because of low publicity or lower awareness of its usefulness. Moreover, people who want to get rid of Wasps may think it risky as it may be hijacked by Wasps if does not kill them :) And ultimately they/we will get some new Wasps neighbourhood :)